# TSQL ISO Month Week Number for ISO Year Week Number

Tags: t-sql

Using TSQL I need to get the ISO Week Number in a Month for a give ISO Year Week Number.

For example: The following code will give me Week #1 for 12/31/2001, which is correct. It is the first Monday in 2002 and the first day of the ISO Year 2002.

```
select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '12-31-2001'); --Week 1 January 2002
```

My question is how do I...

(1) Take the ISO Week Number Example: ISO Year Week Number: 14 for April 4, 2016 (April Week #1).

(2) Now Take ISO Year Week Number 14 and return April Month Week Number = 1 for the example above.

There seems to be nothing in SQL Server to get the ISO Month Week# from the ISO Year Week Number. I have a function I wrote but it is has some hacks to get it to work, but not 100%.

Comment: are you asking how to get the month (Jan for week 1, Dec for week 52) given the ISO_WEEK number?

Comment: Hi Beth, I am asking how to the the Week@ in a month.  Let's say ISO Week #14 of 2016 = April 4, 2016 (April Week Number = 1). I updated my question above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this... but am not sure why you need the ISO_WEEK. Just replace getdate() with your column.

```
select datepart(wk, getdate()) - datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, getdate()), 0)) + 1
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, I need ISO month week because I am using ISO years.. You code will return the month week number, but since ISO years can have 53 weeks, if you attempt to run it on 12-31-2001 you will get December Week #6 but for ISO that month falls into 2002 as January Week #1  select datepart(wk, '12-31-2001') - datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, '12-31-2001'), 0)) + 1.   See this ISO calendar. http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2002

Comment: Ah, i see @RegencySoftware

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to handle getting ISO Month Week Number in functions I decided an easier solution was to create an ISO_Calendar table in SQL Sever.

We know in TSQL you can get the ISO Year Week Number and some a bit of work the ISO Year Number. The ISO Month Week Number is another story.

I build the table shown below with data from 2000 to 2040 by populating all the columns other than the ISO Month number.  Then on a second pass I looped through the table and set the ISO Month number based on the Month# in the Monday Date.

Now if I want to get the ISO Month number for a date I check @Date between Monday and Sunday. In my case I am only concerned with dates between Monday and Friday since this is for a stock analysis site.

```
select @ISOMonthWeekNo = c.ISOMonthWeekNo
from ISO_Calendar c
where @TransDate between c.Monday and c.Sunday;
```

[image: ISO_Calendar]

The advantage is the table is a one time build and easier to verify the accuracy of the data.